# getting "Error 411 (Length Required)" when submitting text for translation

Tags: google-translate

I'm just getting started with Google Translate, and I'm using the Python API.  My source language is Simplified Chinese.

For small bits of text (like an article title), it works fine.

When I tried sending an entire article, I got a 413 error saying my request was too big.  According to running len(text), my article is only 2236 characters long, but that's in Unicode, so maybe it gets blown out beyond the 5000 character suggestion/limit when going over the wire.

When I chop off the string at 1000 unicode characters, I get "Error 411, Length Required".

I'm suspecting that my blind chop at 1000 characters is cutting some character in half, but I can't figure out where the content_length is being set (and there's really no exposed parameters in the translate() method that look likely to help)

Answer (score 4):

Error 411 is fixed by sending data in body rather than in query. i was facing the same issue when i was sending the text in query string.

Comment: I see what you're saying...but the point where the request is generated is buried very deep in the API code.  I don't get the choice of whether to send the data in the body or the query. (Oddly, it always sends a POST with a gigantic URL)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still running into this issue, upgrading to the latest `google-cloud-translate` client should fix the issue. For more information, the PR [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/4977) fixed the problem for me, which was that the client was using GET requests instead of POST requests.

Note: This should also fix a related error of getting 413 (Request Entity Too Large) when sending a list of appropriately sized text to translate.